# Add form template content to an HTML

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to publish form template to my main page which sits in different location:
my Code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/Jquery.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <title>Test</title>
        <style>
        html
        {
            -webkit-background-size:cover;
            -moz-background-size:cover;
            -o-background-size:cover;
            background-size:cover;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select name="Template_Picker" id="Template_Picker">
            <option value="payment">payment</option>
            <option value="identity">identity</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <div id="Templates_Pages">
            <button class="Template" value="Send" id="Template_Button">Show selected</button>
        </div>
        <form action="test/submit.php" method="post" id="submit_template">
            <input type="hidden" id="payment" name="payment" value="payment">
            <center id="output">

            </center>
        </form>
    </body>
    <script src="test/template.js"></script>
</html>
```

I'm trying to take my form template which looks like this:

```
<div id="template" class="template">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" name="Full_Name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Credit Card" name="Credit_Card">
</div>
```

and place her on my main page, so the JS looks like this:

```
$(".Template").click(function(){
    template_p = ($('#Template_Picker').val());
        $.get("test\\"+template_p+".php",function(output){
            $("#template_p").append(output);
//template_p = payment when choosing 
    });
});
```

when on my JS i choose "template_p" it doesnt work, but when i'm using the center id "output" it works, why?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: replace template_p = ($('#Template_Picker').val()); with template_p = $('#Template_Picker').val(); and let see if it works

Comment: @MohsenNewtoa - you mean like this?
$(".Template").click(function(){
    template_p = $('#Template_Picker').val();
        $.get("test\\"+template_p+".php",function(output){
            $("#template_p").append(output);
//template_p = payment when choosing 
    });
});

Because it didnt work

Comment: I don't see an element in your html with the id "template_p". It seems you're trying to append to a non-existing element, or you simply forgot to include it in your code here.

Comment: @El_Vanja - the element is a value which comes from the JS itself after selecting the select box (check the JS comment)

Comment: I see where you might be mistaken. `"#template_p"` does not output the value of the variable. What you want instead is either concatenation `"#" + template_p` or template literals ``#${template_p}``.

Comment: @El_Vanja - question is why and how can i solve this? i tried so many things...
i've also tried just template_p which holds the value but still didnt work since output variable didnt get the update.

Comment: Edited my comment. On a side note, you might want to replace .append() with [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html2). Otherwise, if you select a template multiple times, it will just keep adding over and over.

Comment: @El_Vanja - you mean something like that?
$(".Template").click(function(){
    template_p = ($('#Template_Picker').val());
        $.get("test\\"+template_p+".php",function(output){
            #${template_p}.append(output);
//template_p = payment when choosing 
    });
});
because it didnt work nor the "#" + template_p which i tried before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209050/discussion-between-el-vanja-and-current-redemption).

Comment: @El_Vanja - reply to our chat: i noticed the typo mistake and for unknown reason it still doesnt appears on my screen

Comment: @CurrentRedemption You can always reenter chat, so let's keep it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears like you cannot append an output to an "input" tag.
so i kept using the "center" tag instead.